# How to configure the optimization settings for Oracle Database 21c Express Edition?

Tags: oracle

Is there a similar program to PGTune but for the Oracle? Should I configure it in some file?

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle 21c XE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinw/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-8A8E5F6D-F00E-40BD-B74D-A41CCC502AE9) has few installation options. Express Edition is free and is [limited](https://blogs.oracle.com/database/post/oracle-database-21c-xe-generally-available) to a small amount of CPU threads, memory, and disk space. There's not a lot to optimize.

But if you use Enterprise or Personal edition, the [Database Configuration Assistant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/installing-oracle-database-creating-database.html#GUID-2A1B1AF2-CC36-405A-89EB-72E7A33F7E2B) that comes with the default installation download has several options that are kind of similar to what PGTune offers.

For example, while PGTune lets you select a database type from one of DW, OLTP, Web, Mixed, or Desktop, Oracle DBCA lets your choose between Data Warehouse, General Purpose or Transaction Processing, or Custom Database:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that!